# Replace innerHTML in one element with the innerHTML from another with Javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I would like to replace the innerHTML of a  of a particular class with the innerHTML of a different elemets innerHTML based on that other elements class. I'm trying to dynamically match a header to the selected menu item.

Basically I want to take the innerHTML of whatever has the class "categorySidebarLabelSelected".

```
<a class="categorySidebarLabelSelected">Guest Relations</a>
```

And replace the "Start a document" with "Guest Relations" based on the class "areaTitle".

```
<div class="areaTitle">Start a document</div>
```

so the results would be:

```
<div class="areaTitle">Guest Relations</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using getElementsByClassName.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('areaTitle')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('categorySidebarLabelSelected')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read something like that: http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
var str = $( "categorySidebarLabelSelected" ).text();
$( "areaTitle" ).html( str );
```

Comment: jQuery wasn't tagged.